# The binding contains both an AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement and a secure transport binding element

Tags: wcf, https, x509

We have a requirement as given below:

ESB integration requirement:

Client uses ESB Services (IBM) to provide connectivity for integrating applications and services.’
We have a Service (WCF) that will be called by another vendor through ESB integration
The security requirements for integrating WCF service with ESB is that,  WS-Security for signing but for encryption we should use HTTPS
As per the policy file they shared with us, we should use Asymmetric binding with token sending to only receiver but not for initiator
Message version is SOAP11
They give us a certificate  (X509) which we configure in our WCF service configuration file as Client Certificate and we use our own certificate for our WCF service
WCF implementation to match with their  expected WS-Policy:

We developed a WCF service (.Net 3.5, there is a technical requirement to choose .net 3.5)
The WCF service is configured to use authentication mode MutualCertificateDuplex and for message security version it uses “WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10”
It is also configured to use CustomBinding to match with the ESB’s requirements
Given below is the configuration we are using  for WCF Service:

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="My.Services.ResourceManagementServiceBehavior">
          <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" suppressAuditFailure="true"
            serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure" />
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <certificate findValue="CN=SOAPUIClientCert" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=MyWCFServiceCert" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
              storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="MyServicesCustomBinding">
          <transactionFlow/>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128Rsa15" allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true"
             authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex"
            requireDerivedKeys="false" securityHeaderLayout="Strict" includeTimestamp="true"
                    messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10"
            requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
            <issuedTokenParameters keyType="AsymmetricKey">
              <issuer address=""  binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServicesCustomBinding" />
              <issuerMetadata address="">
                <identity>
                  <certificateReference findValue="CN=MyWCFServiceCert" isChainIncluded="false" />
                </identity>
              </issuerMetadata>
            </issuedTokenParameters>
            </security>
         <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="false"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="My.Services.ResourceManagementServiceBehavior"
        name="My.Services.ResourceManagementService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServicesCustomBinding"
          name="MyBinding" contract="My.Services.IResourceManagementService">
          <!--<identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>-->
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="ResourceManagementService.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Issues that are arising while testing with the above configuration for WCF services:

“Security policy export failed. The binding contains both an AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement and a secure transport binding element. Policy export for such a binding is not supported.  ----> System.InvalidOperationException: Security policy export failed. The binding contains both an AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement and a secure transport binding element. Policy export for such a binding is not supported. 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityBindingElement.ExportPolicy(MetadataExporter exporter, PolicyConversionContext context)

I looked at many blogs and posts but none of them could be really helpful. If I use the authentication mode like “CertificateOverTransport”, it looks like it is working fine (at least not throwing the above error) but the policy it generates (in .svc?wsdl) doesn’t match with ESP required policy. The problem seem to be using HTTPS with with Authentication mode “MutualCertificateDuplex”.

I was in some blogs and some say we don’t need to use HTTPs if we go with Public Key Infrastructure (PKI), but to meet our client’s requirement (matching with their policy) is there any way for me to configure my WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out the ServiceMetadataBehavior section, it probably causes the problem when generating the WSDL policy. Clients will need to configure themselves to same settings but this should be fine.